# Tx_news detail view skip first picture

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I want to render a news item from the News extension, but in the detail view I want to render all images *except* the first image. I have tried this, seek a solution through a iteration, but somewhere is still a fault has occurred.

The code is:

```
{namespace n=GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers}

<f:for each="{media}" as="mediaElement" iteration="iter">
  <f:if condition="{iter.index}" >1>
    <div class="mediaelement mediaelement-image">
      <f:if condition="{mediaElement.link}">
        <f:then>
          <f:link.page pageUid="{mediaElement.link}" target="{n:targetLink(link:mediaElement.link)}">
            <f:image image="{mediaElement}" title="{mediaElement.title}" alt="{mediaElement.alternative}" maxWidth="{settings.detail.media.image.maxWidth}" maxHeight="{settings.detail.media.image.maxHeight}" />
          </f:link.page>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
          <f:if condition="{settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.enabled}">
            <f:then>
              <a href="{f:uri.image(image:'{mediaElement}', width:'{settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.width}', height:'{settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.height}')}" title="{mediaElement.title}" class="{settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.class}" rel="{settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.rel}">
                <f:image image="{mediaElement}" title="{mediaElement.title}" alt="{mediaElement.alternative}" maxWidth="{settings.detail.media.image.maxWidth}" maxHeight="{settings.detail.media.image.maxHeight}" />
              </a>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
              <f:image image="{mediaElement}" title="{mediaElement.title}" alt="{mediaElement.alternative}" maxWidth="{settings.detail.media.image.maxWidth}" maxHeight="{settings.detail.media.image.maxHeight}" />
            </f:else>
          </f:if>
        </f:else>
      </f:if>
    </div>
    <f:if condition="{mediaElement.description}">
      <p class="news-img-caption">
        {mediaElement.description}
      </p>
    </f:if>
  </f:if>
</f:else>
```

Perhaps someone is able to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `f:if`:

```
<f:if condition="{iter.index}" >1>
```

Should be:

```
<f:if condition="{iter.index} > 1">
```

(quote misplaced - whitespace after the `>` is just for prettiness.

Comment: I changed the error by <f:if condition="{iter.index} > 1"> but, no picture is shown. Is there another error to?

Comment: The rest seems to be all okay. Maybe you did not override the template files correctly and the partial is not being rendered?

Comment: The partial FalMediaImage is the right or must I change the detail view of my template?

Comment: That depends completely on your setup, extension versions and extension configuration - I think you should ask this as a new question and include as much as possible of your intended behavior and current setup as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , I have worked in the wrong Partial . Not the FalMediaImage need to be adjusted but the FalMediaContainer .

```
<f:if condition="{media}">
<!-- fal media files -->
  <div class="news-img-wrap">
    <f:for each="{media}" as="mediaElement" iteration="iter">
      <f:if condition="{iter.index} >0">

        <div class="outer">
          <f:if condition="{mediaElement.originalResource.type} == 2">
            <f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaImage" arguments="{mediaElement: mediaElement, settings:settings}"/>
          </f:if>
          <f:if condition="{mediaElement.originalResource.type} == 4">
            <f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaVideo" arguments="{mediaElement: mediaElement, settings:settings}"/>
          </f:if>
          <f:if condition="{mediaElement.originalResource.type} == 5">
            <f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaImage" arguments="{mediaElement: mediaElement, settings:settings}"/>
          </f:if>
        </div>
      </f:if>
    </f:for>
  </div>
</f:if>
```

Maybe it will help someone else who has the same problem as me ?